# How to parse and convert string list to JSON string array in shell command?

Tags: arrays, json, string, bash, jq

How to parse and convert string list to JSON string array in shell command?

```
'["test1","test2","test3"]'
```

to

```
test1
test2
test3
```

I tried like below:

```
string=$1
array=${string#"["}
array=${array%"]"}

IFS=',' read -a array <<< $array; 

echo "${array[@]}"
```

Any other optimized way?

Comment: Can the strings contain spaces, newlines, or double quotes?

Comment: Yes it will be.

Comment: Switch to Python or Perl.

Comment: It's constraint to use shellscript only.

Comment: What do you need to do with the elements of the array?

Comment: Re "*It's constraint to use shellscript only*", Then why was this tagged [tag:jq]?

Comment: So you're asking us to write a JSON parser in `bash` for you? That's not how SO works. SO is not a code writing service. Especially since this is a problem of your own devising. (We'd use existing tools and/or libraries.) If you need help doing so, identify what problem you are having and ask about *that*.

Comment: @ikegami inside shell script we can execute **jq** commands. I was asking for alternate way which would be better in performance and optimized one.

Answer (score 2):

As `bash` and `jq` are tagged, this solution relies on both (without summoning `eval`). The input string is expected to be in `$string`, the output array is generated into `${array[@]}`. It is robust wrt spaces, newlines, quotes, etc. as it uses `NUL` as delimiter.

```sh
mapfile -d '' array < <(jq -j '.[] + "\u0000"' <<< "$string")
```

###### Testing

```sh
string='["has spaces\tand tabs","has a\nnewline","has \"quotes\""]'
mapfile -d '' array < <(jq -j '.[] + "\u0000"' <<< "$string")
printf '==>%s<==\n' "${array[@]}"
```

```
==>has spaces   and tabs<==
==>has a
newline<==
==>has "quotes"<==
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
eval "array=($( jq -r 'map( @sh ) | join(" ")' <<<"$json" ))"
```

Comment: This relies on an external tool, but writing a JSON parser in bash is way outside of the purview of this site.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know of `@sh`. Though it requires `eval`, it's meant for that